# Mathematica - defining variable as positive and real

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

I have a unitary Matrix which consists of Complex coefficients like A, B C etc
I want to have a complex repres. For A like A = a0* Exp (i Phi) and saying that a0 is real and positiv.
I tried the Assumption option but everytime it doesn't work when i try to look at ComplexConj(A) * A - i alwayd get sth like a0 * Conjugate a0 but it should be a0^2.

Can you please help me?

Comment: try using `Simplify` with assumptions: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html

Comment: Thanks - Ok then i would have sth like A = Simplify[a0*Exp(iphi), Element[a0, Reals]] this should work?

Comment: Well you can try it. I cannot verify because I do not have Mathematica right now